# bar/pipe delimited field

Tags: php, postgresql

Anyone know how to insert bar/pipe delimited array in an array field?

With comma its working but when I change it to bar it produces error "malformed array literal"

example (works):

```
insert into table (arrayfield) values ('{"var1","var2","var3"}')
```

example (doesn't work):

```
insert into table (arrayfield) values ('{"var1"|"var2"|"var3"}')
```

btw i'm using postgres 8.2 and PHP and i can't use comma as delimiter for various reasons.

Comment: what is the type of field in `arrayfield` ?

Comment: it says malformed array literal: "{"var1"|"var2"|"var3"}"

Comment: if that field is text and not an array type then why do you need this `{` try to insert like `"var1|var2|var3"` directly

Comment: Why are you trying to use pipes when the column is a `text[]`? That's like trying to insert `'pancakes'` into a `timestamp` column and wondering why it doesn't work. What are these *various reasons* you speak of and what does your code really look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use values without quotes because you know that no pipe is in your data, then you can use:

```
insert into table (arrayfield) select string_to_array('var1|var2|var3','|');
```

If you need that your values are quoted on your pipe-delimited string then it gets complicated. If that's the case then I think you should format and quote properly your array using `ARRAY['val1','val2','val3']` syntax in PHP.